# Why does my F# project build locally but fail on Travis?

Tags: .net, f#, travis-ci

The build for my project is [failing on Travis](https://travis-ci.org/functionauts/Result/builds/75234312) with the following error:

> FSC: error FS0193: The module/namespace 'System.Net' from compilation unit 'System' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'WebClient'

The main project doesn't have any dependencies, and the test project doesn't depend on `System.Net` or `WebClient`, so I'm not sure how that applies here.

Everything works fine locally, so I'm assuming a version mismatch somewhere but haven't been able to identify what.

The output of my local build can be found in [this text file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o34tikvtszq6oe9/local.txt?dl=0).

---

**Update**

Following the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4650) created by [@7sharp9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/607275/7sharp9) it was discovered that this is a Mono [packaging bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=33259).

The suggested [workaround](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4650#issuecomment-133026463) was to reference `FSharp.Core` from the NuGet package instead, which worked for me.

You may wish to [only use the NuGet package when the canonical path is unavailable](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4650#issuecomment-135199724), as I did.

Comment: Total blind shot, but seems you're locally building with FSharp.Core 4.3.1.0 assemblies, while TravisCI uses 3.x. They may have different transitive dependencies. I've googled a bit and it seems that you have already encountered several F# issues with PCLs - this may be another one; fixed in 4.x, present in 3.x. Can you try building it somewhere on 3.x? I'd try to pinpoint it, but have 4.x everywhere as well.

Answer (score 12):

The travis version is building with an `FSharp.Core` from the **GAC**:

> -r:/usr/lib/mono/gac/FSharp.Core/4.3.1.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/FSharp.Core.dll

Whereas your local build is using the `FSharp.Core` at:

> -r:"/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.0.2/lib/mono/xbuild/../Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/FSharp/.NETCore/3.259.3.1/FSharp.Core.dll"

The error you are getting:

> FSC: error FS0193: The module/namespace 'System.Net' from compilation unit 'System' did not contain the namespace, module or type 'WebClient'

Indicated a mismatched `FSharp.Core` where its trying to resolve System.Net references from the Fsharp.Core located in the GAC, the other references in your project are all PCL 259 which will not satisfy this reference.

As to why, could you get travis to build using the diagnostic switch?

Ok so following on, now that there is a diagnostic build linked, the problem is here:

> HintPath /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/../Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/FSharp/.NETCore/3.259.3.1/FSharp.Core.dll does not exist.
>               Reference FSharp.Core resolved to /usr/lib/mono/gac/FSharp.Core/4.4.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/FSharp.Core.dll. CopyLocal = False
>               Reference found at search path {GAC}

The travis instance does not have:

> /usr/lib/mono/xbuild/../Reference Assemblies/Microsoft/FSharp/.NETCore/3.259.3.1/FSharp.Core.dll

So it reverts to the gac.

There was a recent issue where FSharp.Core was not installed to the correct location, maybe this is a manifestation of that.

What I would do is try a different version of mono as described here: http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/csharp/ Maybe try an older one like 3.12 or alpha or beta to try and confirm that this is indeed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this. I updated the question to link to a Travis build where /verbosity:diagnostic

Comment: I added a build matrix. Some versions have different messages but it looks like essentially the same issue: https://travis-ci.org/functionauts/Result/builds/75306324

Comment: Its probably a package install problem on Travis, I logged an issue for you: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4650